# Object is changed in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, methods

I am newbie to python and OOP concepts and i am unable to understand certain things,like why some function change the original object and some doesn't. To understand it better, I have put my confusion in comments in the below code snippet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
from numpy import *
a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],float)
print a
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]) ### Result reflected after using print a
a.reshape(3,2) 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]]) ### Result reflected on IDE after applying the reshape function
print a
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]) ### It remains the same as original value of "a", which is expected.
a.fill(0)
print a 
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]  ### It changed the value of array "a" , why?

############# 
type(reshape) ### If i try to find the type of "reshape" , i get an answer as "function" .
<type 'function'>

type(fill) ### I get a traceback when i try to find type of "fill", why?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    type(fill)
NameError: name 'fill' is not defined
```

**My questions are:**

1) How do i get to know which function(s)(considering "fill" is a function) are going to change my original object value (in my case its "a") ?

2) Considering(correct me if i am wrong) if "fill" is a function then , why its changing the original value of the object "a" ?

3) Why am I getting a traceback when i use type(fill) ?

Comment: a given function can change or not the object input object value. In NumPy many functions come with the `out` parameter, which tells the function to put the answer in this object...

Comment: @Saullo Castro , Thanks for replying, if it is so then it makes little difficult for someone like me(who is new) to learn as how would i know which function has "out" parameter and who hasn't, Is there anyway to see it or it becomes intuitive after learning the language. by the way what is an "out" parameter?

Comment: [check the np.multiply](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) function for example... and see the `out` parameter

Comment: usually the ndarray methods are performing the operations in-place, while the module methods are returning new arrays unless you pass the `out` parameter... actually it seems that when you do `a.sort()` it actually calls `np.sort(a, out=a)`

Comment: I got the point and i think my fried brain is coming to live :), but still multiply is little intuitive as i can think a multiply should have an out but for fill my mind not able to generate such kind of intuition  also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html is not showing any out keyword.

Comment: because `fill()` is a `ndarray` method... and as I mentioned "usually the ndarray methods are performing the operations in-place"... I found curious they don't have a function `np.fill()`

Comment: that is why its also throwing a traceback since it doesn't have np.fill() , got it, can you please put everything as answer , love to accept your answer and I really appreciate your time.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A given function can change or not the input object. In NumPy many functions come with an `out` parameter, which tells the function to put the answer in this object.

Here are **some** NumPy functions with the `out` parameter:

- [NumPy mathematical functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#mathematical-functions)
- [`np.take()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take)
- [`np.choose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choosee)
- [`np.compress()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress)
- [Most of NumPy's logic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logic-functions)

It may happen that these functions are available as a `ndarray` method **without** the `out` parameter, in such case performing the operation in place. Perhaps the most famous is:

- [`ndarray.sort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html)

Some functions and methods do not use the `out` parameter, returning a memory view whenever possible:

- function `np.reshape()` and method `ndarray.reshape()`

The `ndarray.fill()` is one example of subroutine exclusively available as a method, changing the array in-place.

---

Whenever you get a ndarray object or its subclasses it is possible to check if it is a memory view or not based on the `OWNDATA` entry of the `flags` attribute:

```
print(a.flags)

C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the docs or try :)
2. a.reshape() is a method of object a, same for a.fill(). It can do anything with a. That does not apply for reshape (not a.reshape) - that is a function you've imported from numpy nodule in `from numpy import *`.
3. fill is not in numpy module (you have not imported it), it's a member of the `ndarray` object.